# OSMDroid offline maps not loading

Tags: osmdroid

Using osmdroid I am trying to build an offline mapping app.

I am using map tiles which I generated from a file server in PNG format. These are organised in the standard /x/y/z.png file/directory structure and compressed into a .zip file with the internal structure: /mapnik/x/y/z.png

The name of the .zip file is mapnik.zip (I understand the name of this file doesn't matter).

I installed my .apk by buiding it in Android Studio.

I have tried putting the .zip file in /storage/emulated/0/osmdroid and /storage/emulated/0/osmdroid/tiles which is where the cache.db and cache.db-journal files reside (this directory structure existed already).

When I run the app it runs but shows a blank grid instead of a map.

If I change map.setUseDataConnection(false); to (true) it loads the map over the internet and displays it.

Unfortunately I need this to run uniquely offline.

The code for this I got from https://github.com/TizioFittizio/OsmDroidOfflineMap

My MainActivity is as follows:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MapView map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
        map.setUseDataConnection(false);

        map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);

        IMapController controller = map.getController();
        GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(37.370925, -5.972684);
        controller.setCenter(startPoint);
        Marker startMarker = new Marker(map);
        startMarker.setPosition(startPoint);
        startMarker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM);
        map.getOverlays().add(startMarker);

        controller.setZoom(8);
        map.setMinZoomLevel(6);
        map.setMaxZoomLevel(15);
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Alternatively, has anyone else done this and did you use osmdroid? And if not, what did you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

within your zip, it should have the following structure

```
/
/tileSource
/tileSource/0/0/0.png
```

where tile source, in your case, should be `Mapnik` exactly. i.e. `map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);` must match the tile source name. Check out the source for [TileSourceFactory](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/tileprovider/tilesource/TileSourceFactory.java) to get an idea of how to create your own [ITileSource](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/tileprovider/tilesource/ITileSource.java). To get an idea of how the path is created, it is [here](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/tileprovider/modules/ZipFileArchive.java#L81).

there's also a sample dataset [here](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/testzoom4.zip) which would use a tile source with the name of `cb-wac`

if you are still having problems, 
`Configuration.getInstance().setDebugMode(true));
Configuration.getInstance().setDebugTileProviders(true));` may help with debugging

Comment: Just to confirm, this is exactly the structure of my .zip file /mapnik/x/y/z.png

Comment: should be "Mapnik", it is case sensitive

Comment: This is correct, the problem was that I used /mapnik in my zip file. This should have been /Mapnik

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everybody who contributed. I'm totally new at Android dev so I'm grateful for people's patience.

This is working now.

My MainActivity.java is as follows:

```
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
    map.setUseDataConnection(false);
    map.getZoomController().setVisibility(CustomZoomButtonsController.Visibility.ALWAYS);
    map.setMultiTouchControls(true);

    IMapController mapController = map.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(13.0);
    map.setMinZoomLevel(7.0);
    map.setMaxZoomLevel(19.0);

    map.setClickable(true);

    GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(37.3691, -5.97907);
    mapController.setCenter(startPoint);
```

My .zip file is in /storage/emulated/0/osmdroid with the structure as describe EXCEPT that the root of the .zip file is /Mapnik/ ie. case-sensitive.

I am now moving on to overlaying shape files on my map. Wish me luck!